# How do you get syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code in string literal for glsl shader?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, glsl, regl

I'm using Regl which integrates glsl vertex and fragment shaders as strings within a javascript file. I'd like to have syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code apply to the glsl code within the strings, e.g.:

```
var regl = createREGL();

var drawTriangle = regl({

  // fragment shader
  frag: \` // want to apply syntax higlighting to code within string
  precision mediump float;
  uniform vec4 color;
  void main () {
    gl_FragColor = color;
  }`,
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin for Visual Studio Code that mostly accomplishes this task: [vscode-glsl-literal](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=boyswan.glsl-literal). You can search for it within Visual Studio Code and install it there. It only matches these template literals: `glsl`, `glslify`, `frag`, or `vert`. If your code doesn't use one of those (like regl), then add a comment before the string literal with glsl in it, like so:

```
frag: /*glsl*/`
```

Comment: You can also declare a variable `const glsl = x => x[0];`

and then use it like frag: `glsl\`...\``